Extract value from iframe converting var content to text?
I'm trying to get the dollars value that is inside an iframe ($75.12). I can store the iframe doing this:
var frm = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]

but I cannot proceed doing something like
frm.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")

since I get security error about cross origin frame.
Is there a way to store the content of variable frm in plain text? or what do you suggest?
The iframe looks like this:
<iframe class="transact-client-iframe transact-client-open" name="transact-client" src="https://examplesite.com">
'#document (https://examplesite.com)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head></head>
    <body class="transact__layout--flex">
        <div class="animated idx" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="ufst" class="vetyu-apptn">
            <div class="apptn">
            <div class="apptn_header"></div>
            <div class="apptn_content">
                <div class="py-values">
                    <div class="py-values_wallet">
                        <div class="py-values_balance">
                        <div id="vetyu6" class="help-popout vetyu-view"></div>
                        <div class="py-value">$75.12</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row align-center"></div>
                    <div class="py-values_ctas"></div>
                    <div class="py-values_preferences"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form style="display: none"/></form>
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>


Backend Proxy
If you don't control the iframe's source then the best option is to use a backend proxy. There is no straight JS solution to bypass cross-origin security policies safely.

Concept
Send an HTTP request to fetch the HTML content from the iframe source using your backend language, extract your desired value from the content, and return it to the client-side.

Implementation
Node.js example:
Back-End:
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const app = express();

app.get('/get-balance', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // fetch iframe content
        const response = await axios.get('https://examplesite.com');
        const html = response.data;

        // parse HTML with Cheerio
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const balance = $('.py-value').text(); // element containing value

        // return value to client
        res.json({ balance: balance.trim() });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching iframe content:', error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch balance' });
    }
});

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


Front-End
fetch('http://localhost:3000/get-balance')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('Balance:', data.balance);
        document.getElementById('balance').innerText = data.balance;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));

PHP example:
Back-End (PHP Script):
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function getBalance() {
    $url = 'https://examplesite.com';

    // cURL to fetch HTML content
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return ['error' => 'Failed to fetch content'];
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // parse html
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    // locate our element 
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $balanceNode = $xpath->query("//div[@class='py-value']");

    if ($balanceNode->length > 0) {
        $balance = trim($balanceNode->item(0)->textContent);
        return ['balance' => $balance];
    }

    return ['error' => 'Balance not found'];
}

// output response
echo json_encode(getBalance());
?>

Front-End:
fetch('http://domain.tld/get_balance.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
            console.error('Error:', data.error);
        } else {
            console.log('Balance:', data.balance);
            document.getElementById('balance').innerText = data.balance;
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('Fetch error:', error));

